# IBM IHS dynamic routing not working for apis exposed through features (adminCenter/openIDConnect)

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibmhttpserver, dynamic-routing

I have configured dynamicRounting with IHS and liberty (17.x) single collectiven(1 controller, 1 member server) & it is working fine for the applications deployed. But not for openidConnect apis which are exposed from `openidConnectClient-1.0` feature.

```
<openidConnectClient id="H3HO4HuLimleON8UDZaMqAZXF4yZsvMX"
                     clientId="H3HO4HuLimleON8UDZaMqAZXF4yZsvMX"
                     clientSecret="-secret"
                     issuerIdentifier="https://abc/"
                     authorizationEndpointUrl="https://abc"
                     tokenEndpointUrl="https://abc/oauth/token"
                     jwkEndpointUrl="https://abc/.well-known/jwks.json"
                     userInfoEndpointUrl="https://abc/userinfo"
                     userIdentifier="https://abc/userinfo/ab"
                     groupIdentifier="https://abc/userinfo/cd"
                     redirectJunctionPath="/was"
                     accessTokenInLtpaCookie="true"
                     realmName="defaultRealm"
                     authnSessionDisabled="false"
                     mapIdentityToRegistryUser="false"
                     audiences="openid, https://abc/userinfo"
                     responseType="code"
                     scope="openid"
                     signatureAlgorithm="RS256"
                     grantType="authorization_code"
>
</openidConnectClient>
```

The generated `plugin-cfg.xml` is like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--HTTP server plugin config file for webserver1 generated on 2021.10.22 at 08:05:10 GMT-->
<!--Merged HTTP server plugin config file-->
<Config ASDisableNagle="false" AcceptAllContent="false" AppServerPortPreference="HostHeader" 
    ChunkedResponse="false" FIPSEnable="false" IISDisableNagle="false" IISPluginPriority="High" 
    IgnoreDNSFailures="false" RefreshInterval="60" ResponseChunkSize="64" SSLConsolidate="false" 
    TrustedProxyEnable="false" VHostMatchingCompat="false">
   <Log LogLevel="Error" Name="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/logs/webserver1/http_plugin.log"/>
   <Property Name="ESIEnable" Value="true"/>
   <Property Name="ESIMaxCacheSize" Value="1024"/>
   <Property Name="ESIInvalidationMonitor" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="ESIEnableToPassCookies" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="PluginInstallRoot" Value="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/"/>
<!-- Configuration generated using httpEndpointRef=defaultHttpEndpoint-->
<!-- The default_host contained only aliases for endpoint defaultHttpEndpoint.
     The generated VirtualHostGroup will contain only configured web server ports:
        webserverPort=80
        webserverSecurePort=443 -->
   <Property Name="Keyfile" Value="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/webserver1/plugin-key.kdb"/>
   <Property Name="Stashfile" Value="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/webserver1/plugin-key.sth"/>
   <IntelligentManagement>
      <Property name="webserverName" value="webserver1"/>
      <ConnectorCluster enabled="true" maxRetries="5" name="defaultCollective" retryInterval="10000">
         <Property name="uri" value="/ibm/api/dynamicRouting"/>
         <Connector host="was-controller" port="9443" protocol="https">
            <Property name="keyring" value="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/webserver1/plugin-key.kdb"/>
         </Connector>
      </ConnectorCluster>
   <Property name="RoutingRulesConnectorClusterName" value="defaultCollective"/>
</IntelligentManagement>
</Config>
```

I could able to hit the openid api directly (https://localhost:9443/...), but if I try to access it through IHS (https://localhost/was-services-openid/redirect/H3HO4HuLimleON8UDZaMqAZXF4yZsvMX...) it is giving `404` not found.

Same thing happening for `adminCenter` url as well which is hosted on controller server.

I tried even special routingRules, but no change in `plugin-cfg.xml`

```
<dynamicRouting maxRetries="5" retryInterval="10000">
    <routingRules webServers="webserver1">
        <routingRule order="100" matchExpression="URI LIKE '/was-services-openid%'">
            <permitAction>
                <loadBalanceEndPoints>
                    <endpoint destination="cluster=defaultCollective,servicesAppCluster"/>
                </loadBalanceEndPoints>
            </permitAction>
        </routingRule>
    </routingRules>
</dynamicRouting>
```

What am doing wrong ?

**UPDATE:**

from IHS `server-status` I can see this

```
{
   "applications": {
      "/cell/defaultCollective/application/was-home": {
         "editions": {
            "": {
               "webModules": {
                  "/cell/defaultCollective/application/was-home/webModule/was-home.war": {
                     "contextRoot": "/was-home"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "/cell/defaultCollective/application/was-services": {
         "editions": {
            "": {
               "webModules": {
                  "/cell/defaultCollective/application/was-services/webModule/was-services.war": {
                     "contextRoot": "/was-services"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "clusters": {
      "/cell/defaultCollective/cluster/was-controller,%2Fwlp%2Fusr:defaultServer": {
         "servers": {
            "/cell/defaultCollective/node/was-controller,%2Fwlp%2Fusr/server/defaultServer": {
               "state": "STARTED",
               "weight": 2,
               "maintenanceMode": "normal",
               "cloneID": "e8c43d41-38fa-4123-8b63-e89d5b913368",
               "averageResponseTimeInMillis": 0,
               "sessionAffinityCookies": "JSESSIONID",
               "outstandingRequests": 0,
               "applications": {}
            }
         }
      },
      "/cell/defaultCollective/cluster/servicesAppCluster": {
         "servers": {
            "/cell/defaultCollective/node/e60fc3f43af6,%2Fwlp%2Fusr/server/services-app": {
               "state": "STARTED",
               "weight": 2,
               "maintenanceMode": "normal",
               "cloneID": "2b69c058-3953-4cea-a6ca-6f19db78e9de",
               "averageResponseTimeInMillis": 0,
               "sessionAffinityCookies": "JSESSIONID",
               "outstandingRequests": 0,
               "applications": {
                  "was-services": {
                     "state": "STARTED",
                     "outstandingRequests": 0
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "/cell/defaultCollective/cluster/homeAppCluster": {
         "servers": {
            "/cell/defaultCollective/node/ebf4858d8306,%2Fwlp%2Fusr/server/home-app": {
               "state": "STARTED",
               "weight": 2,
               "maintenanceMode": "normal",
               "cloneID": "d240a3db-e107-44ed-9640-1084ccc23ea7",
               "averageResponseTimeInMillis": 0,
               "sessionAffinityCookies": "JSESSIONID",
               "outstandingRequests": 0,
               "applications": {
                  "was-home": {
                     "state": "STARTED",
                     "outstandingRequests": 0
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "version": "ODRLIBX.ODRLIB_a1646.02",
   "connectorGroups": {
      "defaultCollective": {
         "state": "STARTED",
         "failures": 0,
         "connectors": {
            "https://was-controller:9443": {
               "state": "STARTED",
               "failures": 0
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

There are no *contextRoots/applications* exposed from features, even though this [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=collectives-hardening-liberty-collective-endpoints-dynamic-routing) saying that it will expose all the endpoints through dynamic routing - IHS, its just working for deployed application urls.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your whole configuration, we can only guess on some aspects.  The only two required elements are that you have the openidConnectClient-1.0 feature installed on one or more of your servers and the dynamicRouting-1.0 feature installed on your controller(s).  If that is the case and you are still having issues, you could try and look at the server-status page of IHS to get a picture of what IHS knows about your collective.  You can find details on how to configure the server-status page here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/monitoring-ibm-http-server-connections

Once you've configured things, you will need to restart IHS.  You should then see a server-status page at:

http://myihs:port/server-status

In the server-status page look toward the bottom of the page for the `Intelligent Management status` section.  In this section you will see a json dump of the collective as viewed by IHS and the plugin.  You should be able to find
`/cell/defaultCollective/application/com.ibm.ws.security.openidconnect.client` in the applications section.  Inside of that will be the contextRoot element for your oidc connect client.

This would be first pass on isolating the issue.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have provided the server-status info above & it only contains application urls, but not any other urls like adminCenter, openIdConnect features exposed endpoints

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with the version that I am using 17.0.0.4, after moving to 20.x all working as expected.